# Nested standard expandable menu (accordian) behaviour

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-ui-accordion, expandable

I am using the simple accordian script found [here](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-3/) in the noaccordian mode to behave like a standard expandable menu example [here](http://datatags.i-cre8.com/test.php) but the nested menu under classes is not respecting the noaccordian class and is behaving as an accordian, how can I stop this happening ?

I want the nested menu to have the ability to have multiple sections open as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the class="noaccordion" to the nested ul's as well within the Classes menu.  For example:

```
<li> <a href="#">Classes</a>
    <ul class="menu nestedmenu acitem noaccordion">

      <!-- Repeat this LI -->
      <li><a href="#">Built-in Electric &amp; Gas Ovens</a>
        <div class="acitem panel">
          <ul class="noaccordion">
            <li>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="17" class="ovens" />
                Electric: Double</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="18" class="ovens" />
                Electric: with Microwave</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="25" class="ovens" />
                Gas: Single</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="16" class="ovens" />
                Electric: Single</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>...
```

I've created a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvahu/) that show it working as I understand you want it to.  I've only applied the noaccordion code to the first few items.

Comment: I have updated my example page with your suggestion but it doesn't work the same as your fiddle example, I stripped down my example to the absolute bare minimum of code but the nested menu still acts as an accordian